# Why does MySQL allow "group by" queries WITHOUT aggregate functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, standards-compliance, ansi-sql

Surprise -- this is a perfectly valid query in MySQL:

```
select X, Y from someTable group by X
```

If you tried this query in Oracle or SQL Server, you’d get the natural error message:

```
Column 'Y' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in 
either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

So how does MySQL determine which Y to show for each X?  It just picks one.  From what I can tell, it just picks the first Y it finds.  The rationale being, if Y is neither an aggregate function nor in the group by clause, then specifying “select Y” in your query makes no sense to begin with.  Therefore, I as the database engine will return whatever I want, and you’ll like it.

There’s even a MySQL configuration parameter to turn off this “looseness”.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

This article even mentions how MySQL has been criticized for being ANSI-SQL non-compliant in this regard.
http://www.oreillynet.com/databases/blog/2007/05/debunking_group_by_myths.html

My question is:  ***Why*** was MySQL designed this way?  What was their rationale for breaking with ANSI-SQL?

Comment: Let me put it this way.  I see this design choice as being equivalent to a programming language choosing to allow and ignore, say, letting "null" be a left-hand-side value.  e.g. "null = 3".  There's just no reason for letting that happen.  It's the kind of error that is always and dangerously wrong.

Comment: @lumpynose, nonsense, that may have been true pre 5.x

Comment: @lumpynose Can you give a reference to your affirmation?

Comment: Oh, man, I've wanted something resembling this, so much in SQL Server. I've always imagined it as "I want the "PICKANY(col)" aggregation function, or even better the "UNIQUEVALUE(col)" function, which would error if it turns out NOT to be constant across the group. I tend to use "MAX(col)" as my "all the values are the same, give me that value" aggregation function

Comment: Sorry, the above comment was a rambly way of saying "IMO, the answer would be because this functionality is really useful. But I have no citation, other than 'because I want it'".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe that it was to handle the case where grouping by one field would imply other fields are also being grouped:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, COUNT(post.*) AS posts 
FROM user 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN post ON post.owner_id=user.id 
GROUP BY user.id
```

In this case the user.name will always be unique per user.id, so there is convenience in not requiring the user.name in the `GROUP BY` clause (although, as you say, there is definite scope for problems)

Comment: So it was just to save some typing (as in keyboard typing)?  Heh.

Comment: Less columns in GROUP BY clause means faster execution time so it's an optimizing hack. I'm constrantly using `MAX(user.name) AS name` in similar queries on ANSI SQL implementations.

Comment: @wqw: rubbish. user.name is either in the group by or in an aggregate. This is ambiguous at best See comments to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060241/which-is-the-least-expensive-aggregate-function-in-the-absence-of-any/6060419#6060419 Only MySQL allows such bollocks, for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/6642241/27535

Comment: @gbn: Rubbish to what? Using something like `SELECT user.id, ANY(user.name) .. GROUP BY user.id` is not indeterministic if there is a PK on user.id. Obviously the buckets user.name's are picked up from will contain a single unique value -- the name of the user whose id is grouped on. Using `MAX(user.name) AS name` or any other aggragate is awkward at best (though intent is more clearly documented). Could be a case of "It depends" again..

Comment: Postgresql facilitates such functionality and in a controlled manner: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/08/postgresql-recognizing-functional.html

Comment: AFAIK the latest SQL standard demands all selected field to be either group fields or aggregated fields or fields being determinate for the group, such as user.name in above example. So MySQL is compliant to the latest standard insofar as they let you select fields that are neither group fields nor aggregated fields but determinate for the group - a thing that many other dbms don't allow. However, MySQL breaks standard compliance by not checking wether the field is really determinate, thus allowing indeterminate fields as well. [to be continued]

Comment: It is probably hard for a dbms to reliably find out wether a selected field would be determinate or not. Postgres is too restrictive in this point, MySQL too docile.

Answer (score 26):

According to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) (the 5.0 online manual), it's for better performance and user convenience.

Comment: +1, for the MySQL answer :). I use this all the time to avoid doing a sub-query that does an `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` ... you just have to be careful about knowing that the data you receive in non-aggregated columns will be random to all rows that match your conditions.

Comment: LInk is dead, can you update it? or better yet insert the docs here in case it breaks again

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately almost all the SQL varieties have situations where they break ANSI and have unpredictable results.

It sounds to me like they intended it to be treated like the "FIRST(Y)" function that many other systems have.

More than likely, this construct is something that the MySQL team regret, but don't want to stop supporting because of the number of applications that would break.

Comment: This definitely seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL treats this is a single column DISTINCT when you use GROUP BY without an aggregate function. Using other options you either have the whole result be distinct, or have to use subqueries, etc. The question is whether the results are truly predictable.

Also, good info is in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197693/any-reason-for-group-by-clause-without-aggregation-function).

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read in the mysql reference page, it says:
*"You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group."*

I suggest you to read this page (link to the reference manual of mysql): 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score -1):

Its actually a very useful tool that all other fields dont have to be in an aggregate function when you group by a field. You can manipulate the result which will be returned by simply ordering it first and then grouping it after. for instance if i wanted to get user login information and i wanted to see the last time the user logged in i would do this.

Tables

```
USER
user_id | name

USER_LOGIN_HISTORY 
user_id | date_logged_in
```

USER_LOGIN_HISTORY has multiple rows for one user so if i joined users to it it would return many rows. as i am only interested in the last entry i would do this

```
select 
  user_id,
  name,
  date_logged_in

from(

  select 
    u.user_id, 
    u.name, 
    ulh.date_logged_in

  from users as u

    join user_login_history as ulh
      on u.user_id = ulh.user_id

  where u.user_id = 1234

  order by ulh.date_logged_in desc 

)as table1

group by user_id
```

This would return one row with the name of the user and the last time that user logged in.

Comment: My example above is only being used purely to show how you can manipulate the returned result. I'm not saying this is how you would return that information in the simplest way. You would use the MAX function. With much more complex queries it becomes very useful to be able to group without aggregate functions being used on all other fields

Comment: This contrived example is both longer and slower than simply doing a straight forward "max" and therefore doesn't support your claim that this is "a very useful tool" at all. If you can't even contrive an example of it being useful, I seriously question its usefulness. I also don't believe that intentionally using what is frequently indeterminate functionality is going to get *more* useful in *more* complex queries.