# Any reason for GROUP BY clause without aggregation function?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate

I'm (thoroughly) learning SQL at the moment and came across the `GROUP BY`clause.

`GROUP BY` aggregates or groups the resultset according to the argument(s) you give it. If you use this clause in a query you can then perform aggregate functions on the resultset to find statistical information on the resultset like finding averages `(AVG())` or frequency `(COUNT())`.

My question is: is the GROUP BY statement in any way useful without an accompanying aggregate function?

**Update**
Using `GROUP BY` as a synonym for `DISTINCT` is (probably) a bad idea because I suspect it is slower.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is the GROUP BY statement in any way useful without an accompanying aggregate function?

Using `DISTINCT` would be a synonym in such a situation, but the reason you'd want/have to define a `GROUP BY` clause would be in order to be able to define `HAVING` clause details.

If you need to define a `HAVING` clause, you ***have*** to define a `GROUP BY` - you can't do it in conjunction with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Niels: Depends on the data & the data model, but IME I've never had the need that I can recall

Answer (score 6):

You can perform a *DISTINCT* select by using a *GROUP BY* without any *AGGREGATES*.

Answer (score 6):

Group by can used in **Two way** Majorly
1)in **conjunction** with SQL aggregation functions
2)to **eliminate** duplicate rows from a result set

SO answer to your question lies in second part of USEs above described.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: everything below only applies to `MySQL`*

`GROUP BY` is [guaranteed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to return results in order, `DISTINCT` is not.

`GROUP BY` along with `ORDER BY NULL` is of same efficiency as `DISTINCT` (and implemented in the say way). If there is an index on the field being aggregated (or distinctified), both clauses use loose index scan over this field.

In `GROUP BY`, you can return non-grouped and non-aggregated expressions. `MySQL` will pick any random values from from the corresponding group to calculate the expression.

With `GROUP BY`, you can omit the `GROUP BY` expressions from the `SELECT` clause. With `DISTINCT`, you can't. Every row returned by a `DISTINCT` is guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score -2):

It is used for more then just aggregating functions.

For example, consider the following code:

```
SELECT product_name, MAX('last_purchased') FROM products GROUP BY product_name
```

This will return only 1 result per product, but with the latest updated value of that records.

Comment: `MAX()` is an aggregate function.

Comment: @am:Neils is asking about uses without Aggregate function

Comment: It doesn't aggregate, it selects a single value from a list. _An aggregate is a collection of items that are gathered together to form a total quantity_

Comment: It is an aggregate as it takes a group of values, each from a different row and gives you back a single result - that's the definition of aggregate functions in SQL.

Comment: @Max, accepted as an unfair language difference :), guess i didn't understand correctly the Q.