# Merge Multiple records into a single record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query that produces multiple records for a single id. I'm trying to figure out how to merge these multiple records into one record:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, gender, dateofbirth, city, state, zip
FROM t
```

This may give me the following resultset:

```
1, M, 2000-01-01, dallas, tx, 12345
1, M, 2000-01-01, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

What I want is a single record:

```
1, M, 2000-01-01, dallas, tx, 12345
```

A similar scenario occurs when the second row has different data:

```
1, M, 2000-01-01, dallas, tx, 12345
1, M, 2000-01-01, houston, tx, 67890
```

In this case I would just want to pick one of the records and ignore the other in order to only have a single record per id.

Is there a way to do this in PostgreSQL? I've tried coalesce to no avail and is wondering if there is some way to handle this.

Comment: So you have no primary key in that table, no unique column?

Comment: What do you expect if there are two more rows (in addition to the ones you have shown) with `1, M, 2000-01-01, NULL, NULL, 45678` and  `1, M, 2000-01-01, NULL, 'wa', NULL`. Do you always have at least one row where all columns are NOT NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from 
(select a.*, row_number () over (partition by id order by city desc)rn
From tablename a
) b where rn=1
```

The above query will always return one record for an id. If there are multiple values for city,  one with  a value and one with null, the query will get the record which has a value for city.

Comment: I like it - that partition logic always throws me for a loop (no pun intended), but I got this one working as expected. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The query below appears to be working, at least for your sample data.  Have a look at the Fiddle below for a demo.  I used MySQL, because Fiddle tends to break for any other database type.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, MAX(city || ', ' || state || ', ' || zip) AS location
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND
       t1.city || ', ' || t1.state || ', ' || t1.zip = t2.location
```

## SQLFiddle

The trick I use is to concatenate the city, state, and zip into a single string and then choose the max value for group of `id` values.  This would work assuming that it is not possible to somehow form the same string from two different addresses.  I think this would hold true for your US address format.

Comment: The only issue with such approach, is that it may mix data from different rows.

Comment: @michaJlS You're spot on, I posted too fast.  Let's see if I can fix this before Gordon Linoff arrives.

Comment: If I remember, in MySQL you are able to not apply any aggregate func to the field (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197693/any-reason-for-group-by-clause-without-aggregation-function), but I have no idea if that works the same way in psql, neither what it really returns then.