# SQL select distinct substring where like muddleup howto

Tags: sql, select, distinct, substring, max

I've got a table with a field that is similar to this:

```
ANIMAL
========
FISH 54
FISH 30
DOG 12
CAT 65
CAT 09
BIRD 10
FISH 31
DOG 10
```

The field may later have new animals added, such as

```
GOAT 72
DOG 20
```

What I'd like to do is make a `SELECT` query that returns one unique row per animal name, returning a data set with one row per type of animal, which I can later parse to make a list of animals present in my table.

So, after the magic, I'd have

```
FISH 54
DOG 12
CAT 65
BIRD 10
GOAT 72
```

...from which I would make my list.

So far, I've been muddling around with subqueries, `SELECT DISTINCT`, and `SUBSTRING()`, but I feel that any result I came up with would probably pale in comparison to the might of the SO hive mind.  Can someone help?

**UPDATE**

If it helps, my failed attempt sort of illustrates what I want to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring(animal,1,4) FROM table;
```

only now I don't have the whole name, just a substring.  :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will work for SQL Server. If you use something else you need to figure out the corresponding functions to [left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx). Left could of course be replaced with a substring.

```
select distinct left(T.Animal, charindex(' ', T.Animal, 1)-1)
from YourTable as T
```

Result:

```
-------------------------
BIRD
CAT
DOG
FISH
```

In MySQL you would use [left](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [locate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate).
(Code not tested)

```
select distinct left(T.Animal, locate(' ', T.Animal, 1)-1)
from YourTable as T
```

Comment: Closer and closer. That's exactly what I'm looking for...but I'm running MySQL.

Comment: You have done it, my good man.  Thanks muchly.  I've been badge whoring today so I used all my upvotes, but you'll get a +1 too, in time.

Comment: Actually, you are getting one now. :)

Comment: Coming back to this a while later, this bit of code is hugely helpful, thanks again.

Comment: How do I select the count also?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following to get your list of animal names:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(animal, ' ', 1) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: nice! here is the doc for SUBSTRING_INDEX: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
SELECT id, animal, value FROM table GROUP BY animal, id HAVING id = MIN(id)
```

That should get you a list of the animals in the table, each animal with the first entered value.

If you don't need so select the value, then just do:

SELECT animal FROM table GROUP BY animal

Comment: Use @Parkyprg if you need the largest number in the table. Use mine if you don't need the number at all.

Comment: I need yours, but only the first code of each group.  That's a great start though I'll go hit the books - maybe `max` would come in handy.

Comment: Do you have an ID for each row?

Comment: Sure do (well, an auto-increment primary key reference).

Comment: I see where you're going with this but sorry still doesn't work, something is wrong in the `HAVING`...also I don't think I need to select `value` field at the start?  Will keep tweaking...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739474/how-to-select-the-first-row-for-each-group-in-mysql

Comment: If you don't need to select the value, just use my original suggestion. That will get you a list of unique animals in the table.

Comment: The problem is, all of the animals are unique, so they each make their own group: `DOG 10` and `DOG 11` will not group into `DOG`.  But I'll find a new way to do it.  Thanks for your help, I'll +1 one of your other answers (to a different question).  I'll delete this question in an hour or so.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Max(No)
FROM Table
Group By Name
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution too, although generic (my original question was more specific).  But came back to it and still helpful.  +1