# How to return distinct domain names from email address values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL table with values like:

```
+--------------+
| user_email   |
+--------------+
| ab@gmail.com |
| cd@gmail.com |
| ef@yahoo.com |
| gh@yahoo.com |
| ij@gmail.com |
| kl@other.net |
+--------------+
```

I need to return a list of unique domain names from this list of email address, such as:

**gmail.com, yahoo.com, other.net**

So far, I am using the following SQL statement to select this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_email,'@',-1)
```

However, this only solves half of my problem - it is returning domain names. Using DISTINCT did not do the trick. What am I missing?

FYI: This is running on a LAMP stack. Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302027/sql-select-distinct-substring-where-like-muddleup-howto> ?
Maybe that helps.
Good luck!

Comment: It didn't really help, but thanks for the suggestion Fillipe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use group by

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_email,'@',-1) as domain_name FROM user_email group by domain_name
```

Comment: Ah, this led me to the solution. Thanks Hawili!

Comment: This is great, I added ", count(*)" to my query as I was looking for the top domains that I email

Answer (score 0):

SELECT split_part (email,'@',2) as domain_name FROM pytest.emps group by domain_name;