# Using DISTINCT() on a sub-string to group domains on an email DB in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a large MySQL DB of email addresses. I'd like to be able to group/filter them by domain. Is there a way of doing it using DISTINCT()? 
At the moment I'm fetching all via PHP, iterate and split at the @-sign and create an array for each domain. This works fine for smaller data-sets, but is not viable in the long run. Any suggestions?

I'm envisaging something along those lines:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT([part-of-email-after-the-@-sign].EMAIL) FROM CONTACTS
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805166/how-to-return-distinct-domain-names-from-email-address-values-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to find the part after `@`, and then use `DISTINCT` on that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_email, '@', -1) AS domain
FROM Contacts
```

Answer (score 2):

uses INSTR to find '@':

```
select DISTINCT substr(EMAIL, instr(EMAIL, '@') + 1) from CONTACTS;
```

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is substring, seems a few ways of doing this, included supporting links

**Option 1**

Maybe specific to SQL Server, confirming now

```
SELECT DISTINCT(RIGHT(Email, LEN(Email) - CHARINDEX('@', Email))) FROM CONTACTS
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/06/18/sql-server-selecting-domain-from-email-address/

**Option 2**

As seen in [How to select domain name from email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628138/how-to-select-domain-name-from-email-address)

I assume the extra SUBSTRING_INDEX is to remove the .com or ect

```
select (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1),'.',1))

SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1)) FROM CONTACTS
```

**Option 3**

[How to return distinct domain names from email address values in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805166/how-to-return-distinct-domain-names-from-email-address-values-in-mysql)

Makes use of GROUP BY rather than DISTINCT, possible performance factor there so worth testing

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(user_email,'@',-1) as domain_name FROM user_email group by domain_name
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if there's any performance difference between `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` when you're grouping by all the columns in the `SELECT`.