# Returning the 'last' row of each 'group by' in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

Is there a more efficient way of doing the following?

```
select * 
    from foo as a
    where a.id = (select max(id) from foo where uid = a.uid group by uid)
    group by uid;
)
```

This answer looks similar, but is this answer the best way of doing this -  [How to select the first row for each group in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739474/how-to-select-the-first-row-for-each-group-in-mysql/2739528#2739528)

Thanks,

Chris.

P.S. the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uid INT(10) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `uid` (`uid`)
)
```

data:

```
id, uid, value
 1,   1, hello
 2,   2, cheese
 3,   2, pickle
 4,   1, world
```

results:

```
id, uid, value
 3,   2, pickle
 4,   1, world
```

See http://www.barricane.com/2012/02/08/mysql-select-last-matching-row.html for more details.

Comment: This is a correlated subquery. Generally, an uncorrelated subquery will prove faster, as per Devart's example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM foo t1
  JOIN (SELECT uid, MAX(id) id FROM foo GROUP BY uid) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.uid = t2.uid;
```

Then use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html) to analyze queries.

---

```
SELECT t1.* FROM foo t1
  LEFT JOIN foo t2
    ON t1.id < t2.id AND t1.uid = t2.uid
WHERE t2.id is NULL;
```

Comment: This doesn't work as a view - I get "ERROR 1349 (HY000): View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause", whereas my code does.

Comment: I didn't know that you was going to use it for view. ...I have added another one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to do some tests on all three alternatives and report back.  (I managed to make your first solution work for views by making the subquery a separate view.)

Comment: Note, sometimes views are slower than simple queries - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker

Answer (score 10):

Returning the last row of each `GROUP BY` in MySQL with `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT Max(id)
  FROM foo
  WHERE value='XYZ'
  GROUP BY u_id
)
LIMIT 0,30
```

Answer (score 3):

if table is big in size. Make `view` containing all last row id

```
create view lastrecords as (select max(id) from foo where uid = a.uid group by uid)
```

Now join your main query with this `view`. It will be faster.

```
  SELECT t1.* FROM tablename as t1
    JOIN lastrecords as  t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.uid = t2.uid;
```

OR You can do join with last records direct in query also:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tablename as t1
JOIN (SELECT uid, MAX(id) id FROM tablename GROUP BY id) as  t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.uid = t2.uid;
```

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me thanks!

```
SELECT t1.* FROM foo t1
  JOIN (SELECT uid, MAX(id) id FROM foo GROUP BY uid) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.uid = t2.uid;
```

my version:

```
SELECT * FROM messages t1 JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id FROM messages  where uid = 8279 and actv=1 GROUP BY uid ) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id ORDER BY datex desc LIMIT 0,10;
```

this code below doesn't return all rows I want because if max id column is an inactive one then it skips the group even if the group has active rows..

```
select * from messages where uid = 8279 and actv=1 and id In (Select max(id) From messages Group By uid) order by datex desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way : you can select from **selected list that is sorted**.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM foo order by id DESC) AS footbl
group by uid
order by id DESC
```

Answer (score -2):

This code works on me:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo GROUP BY foo.uid 
HAVING MAX(foo.id)
```