# Substitute column value in mysql

Tags: mysql

My sample query:

```
SELECT User.id, User.name, MAX(Track.id) as track_id 
FROM users AS User 
    LEFT JOIN tracks AS Track ON (User.id = Track.user_id) 
GROUP BY Track.id
```

Can i alias `MAX(Track.id)` to "fit" it in `Track`? E.g. something like `MAX(Track.id) as Track.id` So i can than do `ORDER BY Track.id`.

I need that because i already have all APP logic with dynamic `ORDER` and `WHERE` and only in one case i need to do `GROUP BY`, also i do all that stuff using ORM. So i want to leave all APP logic as is but in that particular case add aggregate field and `GROUP BY` and in my APP still use `Track.id` in meaning `MAX(Track.id)` is it possible?

Comment: You better explain what you want your query to do, since your question doesn't correlate with SQL principles too much.

Comment: I want to select users and their latest track_id

Comment: `MAX(Track.id)` --- that's how you select the "latest" value. And it's already in your query.

Comment: Relevant though: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1313120/251311 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/251311 http://stackoverflow.com/q/9192673/251311

Comment: yes, i know it. Than i want to alias it to use in APP as Track.id, because it's only one case, in other cases i will select user and all tracks without `group by` and i don't want to rewrite all calls to `Track.id` in all my APP

Comment: " Than i want to alias it to use in APP as Track.id" --- `track.id` is a real column name. You cannot "alias to it". That's why I asked to tell about the *real* issue, not about your broken "solution"

Comment: It's what my question was: can i substitute real column value to computed one or not ant only in runtime.

Comment: You technically can create a view and make it looking like a table with values calculated in runtime. But I still think you are solving a wrong problem (you don't want to share it though) - since your query is broken by design: `Track.name` is not what you think.

Comment: I'm already share my problem: i'm already have my app working. And i widely use that column (`Track.id`). But now in one case (if user select checkbox) i need to do group by `Track.id` and show only last one. So if i will add `MAX(Track.id) as track_id` field i than need to rewrite all calls to `Track.id` in my application to check `isset($response['track_id'])?$response[track_id]:$response['Track']['id']`. I don't want to do that.

Comment: first thing: your query is wrong. `Track.Name` is a **random** name, not the name from the latest track. Next - what explodes the result set into nested arrays? How you know that `Track` table has an `id` column? Is there some mapping for it? If so - how it would distinguish between `user.id` and `track.id` which in result set would be returned as `id`? (only column names/aliases are kept in result set)

Comment: Newermind Track.name. It's simplified query. My actual query much more complicated. I have my question already answered. If i can't substitute real value by computed one i will go the other way. Thanks.

Comment: It all done by ORM and will become `$response['User']['id']` and `$response['Track']['id']`

Answer (score 1):

Use backtick(`) in naming alias or in selecting column like this

```
SELECT User.id, User.name, Track.name, MAX(Track.id) as `Track.id` 
from users as User 
LEFT JOIN tracks as Track ON (User.id = Track.user_id) 
GROUP BY Track.id
```

backtick are uses to escape MySQL reserved words.

Comment: Such approach will not replace actual `Track`.`id` column. It become extra column `Track`.`Track.id`

Comment: then make it `id` instead