# MySQL select latest input in each group

Tags: mysql

So I have one table

```
Table_A
ID    Code       Arrival date
3      A3           3/1/15
2      A2           1/1/15
1      A3           2/1/15
```

ID is auto increment, arrival date can be the same of the same code,

So what I want my MySQL query to do is to group all those codes with arrival date fits a range of dates and group them by code then choose only the latest input

What I have so far

```
Select * from Table_A
Where 'Arrival date' between 1/1/15 and 3/1/15 and group by Code
```

But somehow this only return the earliest code, how I can solve this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using 1/1/15 instead of the default `DATE` format (YYYY-mm-dd)?

Comment: Not really just cause I'm typing with my phone, sorry

Comment: Does this work? `SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE STR_TO_DATE('Arrival date', '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-03' GROUP BY Code asc ORDER BY 'Arrival date' DESC`

Comment: No, the problem is which the grouping, only focus on the grouping part, the rest is fine, I want to achieve like I group those satisfied inputs with same code, but I just want the earliest inputs within those groups, which is with the biggest id number

Comment: I don't think so it will work, syntax error

Comment: What about this? `SELECT id, Code, MAX(\`Arrival date\`) AS \`Arrival date\` FROM Table_A WHERE \`Arrival date\` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-03' GROUP BY Code`

Comment: No it won't work as if the codes are having same arrival date it will be duplicated? I want specifically the id should be biggest of number in each group only will be selected

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Seems more efficient to run multiple queries with your conditions then `UNION` them.

```
(SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE 'Arrival date' 
 BETWEEN 1/1/15 AND 3/1/15 AND Code = A2 
 ORDER BY 'Arrival date' DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE 'Arrival date' 
 BETWEEN 1/1/15 AND 3/1/15 AND Code = A3 
 ORDER BY 'Arrival date' DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Ordering by date allows us to sort the rows from newest to oldest (DESC) and return only the newest row. Hopefully it's what you need.

Comment: No, I want to return the latest row within each group, and not only the latest row

Comment: @AlejandroIván You are right, changing my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could help you:

```
SELECT
    MAX(id) AS id,
    Code,
    `Arrival date`
FROM
    Table_A
WHERE
    `Arrival date`
        BETWEEN
            '2015-01-01'
            AND
            '2015-01-03'
GROUP BY
    Code
```

Comment: I see this but I don't know how to implement in my system http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192673/returning-the-last-row-of-each-group-by-in-mysql