# Doctrine / SQL query MAX with GroupBy

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

My goal is to select the column with the highest createdAt, grouped by a user.

If i do the following:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('qb1');
$q = $qb
  ->select('pbs, MAX(pbs.createdAt) AS HIDDEN pbs_created')
  ->add('from', 'MyEntity pbs')
  ->groupBy('pbs.user')
  ->orderBy('pbs_created', 'ASC')
  ->getQuery();
return $q->getResult();
```

I get:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| id_0 | createdAt_3         | sclr_5              | project_id_7 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| 2137 | 2014-10-07 10:52:29 | 2017-04-25 15:42:42 |          116 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
| 5123 | 2015-11-02 15:02:55 | 2017-05-02 05:36:18 |          118 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

The Problem is that i get the max value but the returned row contains not the value from max.

How can i get the newest createdAt grouped by a user with associated entity data?

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing todo with ordering.
`MAX()` gives you the *maximal value* but **not the row with maximal value**

Look at these SO questions

- [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)
- [Returning the 'last' row of each 'group by' in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192673/returning-the-last-row-of-each-group-by-in-mysql)

The problem is - both solutions are pretty hard to achieve with Doctine's QueryBuilder. 
Subqueries are possible though  - http://melikedev.com/2013/06/07/php-doctrine-dql-select-subquery/

Comment: I already thought someting like this and built a native query with your suggested solutions ( sub select ).

Comment: Wondering why DQL cannot handle a sub select.

Comment: Link isn't working anymore

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the orderBy?
Like this:

```
->orderBy('pbs_created', 'DESC')
```

Comment: Yes. the orderBy will just affect after group by, so it will just sort your "old" or "not-wanted" entries.