# How does this SQL achieve 'row_number' function?

Tags: mysql

I want to achieve a function in `MySQL` like

```
select * from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by uid order by last_login desc) as rn 
    from test) 
where rn = 1
```

Then I found a magical SQL as follows:

```
select * from test as a 
where typeindex = (select max(b.last_login) 
                   from test as b 
                   where a.uid = b.uid);
```

It can fit my requirement and efficiency is good but it's a bit difficult for me to understand the procedure of this query particularly the `where a.uid = b.uid` in the sub-query.

Could any body give a brief flow of how this query works? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It is a Correlated Subquery. Refer documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Comment: Also, the "magical SQL" query has much better/performant alternatives available. Check this answer, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192763/2469308

Comment: The magical query would be my preferred solution. You should check explain to see which is more efficient.