# Selecting first and last values in a group

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a MySql table consisting of daily stock quotes (open, high, low, close and volume) which I'm trying to convert into weekly data on the fly. So far, I have the following function, which works for the highs, lows, and volume:

```
SELECT MIN(_low), MAX(_high), AVG(_volume),
CONCAT(YEAR(_date), "-", WEEK(_date)) AS myweek
FROM mystockdata
GROUP BY myweek
ORDER BY _date;
```

I need to select the first instance of _open in the above query. So for example, if there was a holiday on Monday (in a particular week) and stock market opened on Tuesday, _open value should be selected from the Tuesday that's grouped into its week. Similarly, the close value should be the last _close from that week.

Is it possible to select something like FIRST() and LAST() in MySql so that the above could be wrapped up within a single SELECT rather than using nested select queries?

Here's my table's create statement to get an idea of the schema:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TABLE `mystockdata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `symbol_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `_open` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `_high` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `_low` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `_close` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `_volume` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `add_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Symbol_Id` (`symbol_id`,`add_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Update: There are no nulls, wherever there's a holiday/weekend, the table does not carry any record for that date.

Comment: As you know, `FIRST` and `LAST` as you described don't exist in MySQL. It may be possible with one query, but it depends on your table schema… Update your post.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Please see my edits above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739474/how-to-select-the-first-row-for-each-group-in-mysql

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8, the preferable solution would make use of the window functions [FIRST_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value) and/or [LAST_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_last-value), which are now available. Please have a look at [Lukas Eder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52412604/833073).

But if you're using an older version of MySQL, those functions are not
supported. You have to simulate them using some kind of workarounds,
for example you could make use of the aggregated string function [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) that creates a set of all `_open` and `_close` values of the week ordered by `_date` for `_open` and by `_date desc` for `_close`, and extracting the first element of the set:

```
select
  min(_low),
  max(_high),
  avg(_volume),
  concat(year(_date), "-", lpad(week(_date), 2, '0')) AS myweek,
  substring_index(group_concat(cast(_open as CHAR) order by _date), ',', 1 ) as first_open,
  substring_index(group_concat(cast(_close as CHAR) order by _date desc), ',', 1 ) as last_close
from
  mystockdata
group by
  myweek
order by
  myweek
;
```

Another solution would make use of subqueries with `LIMIT 1` in the `SELECT` clause:

```
select
  min(_low),
  max(_high),
  avg(_volume),
  concat(year(_date), "-", lpad(week(_date), 2, '0')) AS myweek,
  (
    select _open
    from mystockdata m
    where concat(year(_date), "-", lpad(week(_date), 2, '0'))=myweek
    order by _date
    LIMIT 1
  ) as first_open,
  (
    select _close
    from mystockdata m
    where concat(year(_date), "-", lpad(week(_date), 2, '0'))=myweek
    order by _date desc
    LIMIT 1
  ) as last_close
from
  mystockdata
group by
  myweek
order by
  myweek
;
```

Please note I added the [LPAD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) string function to `myweek`, to make the week number always two digits long, otherwise weeks won't be ordered correctly.

Also be careful when using substring_index in conjunction with group_concat(): if one of the grouped strings contains a comma, the function might not return the expected result.

Comment: Thanks, fthiella. The first method using `GROUP_CONCAT` works perfectly as needed!

Comment: Beautiful.  That cuts my execution time down from 12 minutes to 12 seconds.  Thanks!

Comment: This query (like the OP's query, btw) wouldn't work with MySQL's strict mode turned on (or simply [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)). The `_date` column would be undefined in both the `GROUP_CONCAT`'s `ORDER BY` clause as well as in the `SELECT` query's `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @LukasEder i have updated my answer, as the preferable solution is to make use of windows functions that are now available in MySQL8. Thanks for your comment and for your answer

Comment: @fthiella Sure, but I also like your solution, except that it only works in non strict mode. It's definitely possible to make your approach work in strict mode as well. E.g. you could calculate `myweek` in a derived table and then reference only `myweek`, not `_date`, which shouldn't be referenced. Also, I've just noticed there's an error in your correlated subqueries. You're only comparing `WEEK(_date)`, not also `YEAR(_date)`. Here as well, `myweek` should have been used.

Comment: @LukasEder thank you, that's definitely a bug also. I have updated my answer (it might still be useful whenever MySQL8+ is not available), i didn't use a derived table but it should be fixed. Also better to use lpad on the week number in order to sort weeks correctly. Now it should be okay :)

Comment: You didn't even show an example of how to use FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE.

Answer (score 12):

Starting with MySQL 8, you would ideally use [window functions](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/) for the task:

```sql
WITH 
  t1 AS (
    SELECT _low, _high, _volume, CONCAT(YEAR(_date), "-", WEEK(_date)) AS myweek
    FROM mystockdata
  ),
  t2 AS (
    SELECT 
      t1.*, 
      FIRST_VALUE(_open) OVER (PARTITION BY myweek ORDER BY _date) AS first_open,
      FIRST_VALUE(_close) OVER (PARTITION BY myweek ORDER BY _date DESC) AS last_close
    FROM t1
  )
SELECT MIN(_low), MAX(_high), AVG(_volume), myweek, MIN(first_open), MAX(last_close)
FROM t2
GROUP BY myweek
ORDER BY myweek;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will likely need to `COALESCE` function to get the first value.  However, you need to make sure that days without data (weekends and holidays) have a null value for `_open` on those days without data.

Usage would be:

```
SELECT MIN(_low), MAX(_high), AVG(_volume), COALESCE(_open)
CONCAT(YEAR(_date), "-", WEEK(_date)) AS myweek
FROM mystockdata
GROUP BY myweek
ORDER BY _date;
```

For the last() value, I can only think of a pretty hacky solution, which would be to use `GROUP_CONCAT` and then string manipulation to get the last value from the list.  So perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(_low), MAX(_high), AVG(_volume), COALESCE(_open), SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(_close), ',', -1)
CONCAT(YEAR(_date), "-", WEEK(_date)) AS myweek
FROM mystockdata
GROUP BY myweek
ORDER BY _date;
```

Note you could also use the `GROUP_CONCAT` approach for the first item instead of coalesce if you wanted consistent looking query

```
SELECT MIN(_low), MAX(_high), AVG(_volume), SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(_open), ',', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(_close), ',', -1)
CONCAT(YEAR(_date), "-", WEEK(_date)) AS myweek
FROM mystockdata
GROUP BY myweek
ORDER BY _date;
```

For `GROUP_CONCAT` to work properly you also need to make sure the dates without values have null in `_open` and `_close` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you need to do:

1. group by PRODUCTID
2. within each group, order by LOCATION
3. select the FIRST price for the same product as ordered by LOCATION

Putting them together, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT PRODUCTID, 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(LOCATION AS CHAR) ORDER BY LOCATION DESC), ',', 1) AS LOCATION,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(PRICE AS CHAR) ORDER BY LOCATION DESC), ',', 1) AS PRICE
FROM ProductLocation
GROUP BY PRODUCTID;
```

Note that MySQL does not have FIRST() and LAST() aggregate functions for GROUP BY but such FIRST() AND LAST() can be simulated by using GROUP_CONCAT() and SUBSTRING_INDEX() functions.

Comment: The columns / tables don't exist in the OP's question