# Possible to select only 1 row for usernames, even though multiple rows which include usernames are unique

Tags: sql, distinct

I am trying to select all usernames that have a at least one windows operating system. Some users have many windows operating systems, but I really only need to know if they have at least one.

I know `DISTINCT` can filter out duplicates, but the issue is these rows are unique, if they have more than one OS. For example:

```
JohnDoe windows 10;
JohnDoe windows 97;
JohnDoe windows 7;
JennyDoe windows 10;
```

In this case, JohnDoe will be selected 3 times because he has 3 unique operating systems.

Is there a way to essentially say, if an instance of this username appears, only select one row?

Comment: SSMS is an IDE for SQL Server, it doesn't work for MySQL. Please correct your tags. Though your question doesn't appear to be able SSMS at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the first row for each group in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739474/how-to-select-the-first-row-for-each-group-in-mysql)

Comment: In your sample data, is e.g. `JohnDoe windows 10` the data in your `username` field, or are there multiple fields, e.g. the field `username` contains `"JohnDoe"` and another field, perhaps `operating_system`, contains `windows 10`?

Comment: One would hope so, @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica, otherwise the OP has a much larger problem. ;)

Comment: consider a case expression for your OS `case when OS like '%windows%' then 1 else 0 end   as winOS` and then use an analytic `row_number() over (partition by user order by winOS, OS)` as a CTE and then select from the CTE where RN = 1   or use a cross apply... which is a bit more efficient if supported.  Assumes analytic is supported...

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Ah, yes the data has multiple fields. I'm currently browsing through the other pages Larnu sent me. I think this is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct username
  from your_table
  where operating_system like '%windows%'
```

Based on the data shown in the question, this will return

```
JohnDoe
JennyDoe
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d7efacd4b5f1946a94380692fbf3b36)

Comment: or if you need to see one of the operating_system just add a Max(Operating_system) to the select and group by username removing distinct.  This is clean.

Comment: Well, I'm sad to give you the answer... mainly because I have used and know distinct. But I simply just only included the users username in the select statement, therefor using distinct would work and did work in this case.....

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `username` and `os` - stored in two separate columns.

Let's create the table with some data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_os` ( username varchar(100), os varchar(100));

INSERT INTO user_os values 
('JohnDoe', 'windows 10'),
('JohnDoe', 'windows 97'),
('JohnDoe', 'windows 7'),
('JennyDoe', 'windows 10'),
('Jessica', 'Ubuntu');
```

Now we can look for `'windows'` string inside `os` column and group by it. You'll get `1` - for users with at least 1 windows os or `0` - for others.

```
SELECT username, instr(os, 'windows') AS at_least_1_windows
FROM user_os
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

The result:

```
username  at_least_1_windows
--------  ------------------
JennyDoe  1
Jessica   0
JohnDoe   1
```

Answer (score 1):

In sql, you can use Tsql  row_number codes and so select only rows that row number is 1 when you want select only one row between many duplicate rows better use this code because distinct is very slow

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    usernam varchar(100),
    os varchar(100),
  

)

insert into table_name
values('john','windows10')

insert into table_name
values('john','windows7')

 insert into table_name
values('david','windows7')

select 
usernam,

    row_number() over (partition by [usernam] order by os  desc)rownum
   
from 

   table_name t
```

so result is

[image]

```
so if you add this query select only one record 

select tbl.usernam from (
select 
usernam,

   row_number() over (partition by [usernam] order by os  desc) rownum
   
from 

   table_name 
   ) tbl
   
   where rownum=1
```

so result is
[image]

also you can show other fields

```
select tbl.usernam,tbl.os from (
    select 
    usernam,
os,
       row_number() over (partition by [usernam] order by os  desc) rownum
       
    from 

       table_name 
       ) tbl
       
       where rownum=1
```

the result is:
[image]

according this your query speed is very well.