# select unique rows based on single distinct column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select rows that have a `distinct email`, see the example table below:

```
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
| id | title   | email             | commentname |
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
|  3 | test    | rob@hotmail.com   | rob         |
|  4 | i agree | rob@hotmail.com   | rob         |
|  5 | its ok  | rob@hotmail.com   | rob         |
|  6 | hey     | rob@hotmail.com   | rob         |
|  7 | nice!   | simon@hotmail.com | simon       |
|  8 | yeah    | john@hotmail.com  | john        |
+----+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

The desired result would be:

```
+----+-------+-------------------+-------------+
| id | title | email             | commentname |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------------+
|  3 | test  | rob@hotmail.com   | rob         |
|  7 | nice! | simon@hotmail.com | simon       |
|  8 | yeah  | john@hotmail.com  | john        |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Where I don't care which `id` column value is returned.
What would be the required SQL?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Quick one in TSQL

```
SELECT a.*
FROM emails a
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT email,
    MIN(id) as id
  FROM emails 
  GROUP BY email 
) AS b
  ON a.email = b.email 
  AND a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: Wow that was fast guys!:) laptop's answer was the shortest and easiest, thanks!

Comment: The `distinct` keyword is not necessary here. Also, it seems like a join on just `id` would do the trick as well.

Comment: I have a huge table with primary key an aggregate of two columns, it is  not working in that case

Comment: @downvoter , what do you mean by not working, perhaps will be another question?

Comment: Excellent, I changed the min to max to get the last row in the duplicate instead of first

Answer (score 45):

I'm assuming you mean that you don't care which row is used to obtain the `title`, `id`, and `commentname` values (you have "rob" for all of the rows, but I don't know if that is actually something that would be enforced or not in your data model). If so, then you can use windowing functions to return the first row for a given email address:

```
select
    id,
    title,
    email,
    commentname

from
(
select 
    *, 
    row_number() over (partition by email order by id) as RowNbr 

from YourTable
) source

where RowNbr = 1
```

Comment: This is the best solution, because it can apply to duplicate rows that do not have a unique identity column, or ones that do.

Comment: ....Yes this solved the issue for me....the solution above only grouped the table data together.....i.e for Microsoft SQL 2008 Server/data .........thanks Adam......

Comment: This is a really good solution that works great for smaller tables. Is there a way to do this without having to list each column in the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **MySql 5.7 or later**, according to these links ([MySql Official](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1225144/2270563)), we can select one record per `group by` with out the need of any aggregate functions.

So the query can be simplified to this.

`select * from comments_table group by commentname;`

Try out the query in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e7fc/5/0)

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is tagged with tsql and sqlserver.

Comment: Even though it was the right answer to the wrong question I ended up here looking for this solution for mysql so take my updoot

Comment: Nice solution deserves more respects

Comment: didn't work with mysql  Ver 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't care which id to return I stick with MAX id for each email to simplify SQL query, give it a try

```
;WITH ue(id)
 AS
 (
   SELECT MAX(id)
   FROM table
   GROUP BY email
 )
 SELECT * FROM table t
 INNER JOIN ue ON ue.id = t.id
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM emails GROUP BY email;