# How to skip the first and consider the second row whenever duplicate cells come in a column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have the following table. The startdatetime column is repeated when the duration is over a day. What I want is to write a query which skips the first row and count the difference of the second row whenever a duplicate cell in a startdatetime column come. E.g. In the case of following sample table the output I want is given in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
    ([Name] varchar(50), [StartDateTime1] datetime, [EndDateTime2] datetime, Diffy int)
;

INSERT INTO Test
    ([Name], [StartDateTime], [EndDateTime2], [Diffy])
VALUES
    ('ABC', '2015-07-21 16:08:02.000', '2015-07-21 16:18:10.000', '608' ),
    ('ABC', '2015-07-21 16:18:10.000', '2015-07-21 23:06:46.000', '24516' ),
    ('ABC', '2015-07-21 16:18:10.000', '2015-07-23 12:37:35.000', '159565' ),
    ('ABC', '2015-07-23 17:33:35.000', '2015-07-24 11:07:00.000', '63205' )
;


╔══════╦════════╗
║ Name ║ Diffy  ║
╠══════╬════════╣
║ ABC  ║    608 ║
║ ABC  ║ 159565 ║
║ ABC  ║  63205 ║
╚══════╩════════╝
```

The simple query I used is

```
Select 
 Name,
 DateDiff(SECOND, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) As Diffy
From
 Test
```

Comment: Order isn't guaranteed.  so by "Second row" you mean the one with the largest enddatetime2?  Is there a possibility of more than 2 records?  would you always want the one with the largest endDatetime2?

Comment: I wonder how Diffy is `INT` but store strings

Comment: I achieved the above task using the [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273987/select-unique-rows-based-on-single-distinct-column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273987/select-unique-rows-based-on-single-distinct-column)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `group by`:

```
Select Name,
       DateDiff(SECOND, StartDateTime, MAX(EndDateTime)) As Diffy
From Test
GROUP BY Name, StartDateTime;
```

Comment: to skip the second row?

Comment: @Nimko . . . This doesn't "skip" the second row.  It only considers the last `EndDateTime` for each `StartDateTime`, which has the same effect if there are exactly two duplicates.

Comment: Not it is only a sample of 22 lac records. On every day change the database duplicate the last transaction like second and third row in the above sample table.