# MSSQL Query should return same as MYSQL

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I've MYSQL Query and working fine
The QUERY IS:

```
select tst_type, count(tst_type) tot from tst_type where project='JupiQA';
```

The above Query returns single record If I'm adding `GROUP BY tst_type` in this query it returns multiple values.

The Query I  tried in MSSQL without `GROUP BY tst_type` ,its showing Error

> ERROR IS: Column 'tst_type.tst_type' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

After that added `GROUP BY tst_type` in MSSQL query,then working fine and returns multiple value.

But my requirement is it should return same as MYSQL without adding GROUP BY fn OR should return single value like MYSQL

Comment: What does that single record represent in your first query? The total number of that particular `tst_type` records, or a count of all records?

Comment: It returns total count of all records.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows this behavior, but I don't know of any other DBMS that lets it happen. If you want MySQL and MSSQL queries to behave the same, add the SQL Mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. MySQL will now throw the error properly.

Also check out this SO post:
[Why does MySQL allow "group by" queries WITHOUT aggregate functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225144/why-does-mysql-allow-group-by-queries-without-aggregate-functions)

Answer (score 0):

When doing a `COUNT()` as you're doing here, the `GROUP BY` is required to get the correct results. See the [MySQL docs on the function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

You can use a `count(*)` without any other fields to get a count of the total number of records. Otherwise, you must use `GROUP BY`.

IMHO your requirement for this query is backwards; aggregate functions require `GROUP BY` to behave properly/consistently when non-aggregate fields are included in the `select`. MSSQL is behaving properly, MySQL is not.