# mySQL select from a list from another select

Tags: mysql, subquery

A have a table so :

```
id | name | idparent | info
 1 | AA   |          | x
 2 | BB   |          | 
 3 | CC   |          | x
 4 | DD   | 1        |
 5 | EE   | 1        |
 6 | FF   | 2        |
 7 | GG   | 2        |
 8 | HH   | 3        |
 8 | HH   | 4
```

and what i want to do is done like this with mySQL/PHP :

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE info LIKE 'x'
```

and in PHP

```
for i in each id result of the first request :
  SELECT id, name FROM table where idparent = i ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
endFor
```

for instance, the result could be :

```
4 |DD
8 |HH
```

and because of the RAND(), the result could be too :

```
5 |EE
8 |HH
```

but it is not so beautiful, is there a possibility to do this in just one request ?

I have tried several idea but without success, i don't enumerate here, in order not to pollute the comprehension my subject :)

Thank's in advance for your answer

Comment: check the updated answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution using `sub-queries`, which is only valid for MySQL, since the `GROUP BY` behavior of MySQL is a extension for SQL standard.

## MySQL solution using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  t.id, t.name 
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, idparent
    FROM table 
    where idparent IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE info LIKE 'x')
    ORDER BY RAND()
) t
GROUP BY t.idparent;
```

Solution for non-MySQL, by allocation of `group rank` with `user variable`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, name, idparent,
        IF(idparent = @last_idparent, @grp_rank := @grp_rank + 1, @grp_rank := 1) as grp_rank
    FROM table CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp_rank := 1, @last_idparent := NULL) param
    where idparent IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE info LIKE 'x')
    ORDER BY RAND()
) t
WHERE t.grp_rank = 1;
```

Comment: It works, and i was surprised of this, but now i understand why :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225144/why-does-mysql-allow-group-by-queries-without-aggregate-functions


Thank's !

Comment: Juste for curiosity, have you a solution for a other SQL database, because the behaviour of "group by" exist just for mySQL.

Comment: it's easy. I am on the phone. One way is to allocate 1....N for each group in the inner sub query, and filter out 1 in the outer query

Comment: Coul'd you give me an example for this idea with an allocation ? Thank's !

Comment: probably, with rank function ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql ), but in order to use "IN", the subrequest should return just one row....

Comment: Updated the answer with the allocation method. pls try if it works. I have no sample data to test for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`SELECT id, name FROM table natural join (SELECT id as idparent FROM table WHERE info LIKE 'x') as T  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`

I hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: this proposition return just one line, it was one of my try :/

Comment: @user3671363 actually it is very diifficult to test without sample data. Can you please post a sqlfiddle. Mean while i will try to figure out something else.

Comment: @user3671363 just check my updated solution and let me know if it works. Just to know if i am correct......I know that you have already accepted the answer.

Comment: thank's to try. Sorry, it's don't work because the LIMIT limits the result for the totality not by idparent.

Comment: @user3671363 so if i remove `LIMIT 1`  will it work?

Comment: no, but it give me an idea for the upgrade of the question, i give it after the upgrade