# Is it possible to consolidate records from a SELECT statement that have duplicate column values with another record in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider that I have the following tables/entities:

`Posts`

| id | user_id | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Article 1 | Lorem ipsum |
| 2 | 1 | Article 1 | Lorem ipsum |
| 3 | 1 | Article 2 | Lorem ipsum 2 |
| 4 | 2 | Article 3 | Lorem ipsum |

`Users`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Timothy Fisher |

Notice that there are two posts from the user with an ID of 1 that have the same title and content. There was an error at the application level that allowed a user to submit a post twice in the past, leading to "duplicate" records.

I'm looking to query all of the posts, but consolidate the posts for each user that have duplicate titles **and** content.

The ideal result set would look like this:

| post_id | author_name | title | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | Article 1 | Lorem ipsum |
| 3 | John Doe | Article 2 | Lorem ipsum 2 |
| 4 | Timothy Fisher | Article 3 | Lorem ipsum |

```sql
SELECT
  posts.id as post_id,
  users.name as author_name
  posts.title,
  posts.content
FROM
  posts
INNER JOIN
  users
ON
  posts.user_id = users.id;
```

Whether or not the query pulled post `1` or `2` for John Doe wouldn't matter. In the actual databases, I have timestamps so I'd likely just pull the latest one.

Is this possible with SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use a fake aggregation function and  group by

```
SELECT 
  min(posts.id) as post_id,
  users.name as author_name
  posts.title,
  posts.content
FROM  posts
INNER JOIN  users  ON   posts.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY   users.name, posts.title, posts.content
```

Comment: I guess I didn't even consider group by. So wait, would this work without the aggregation function? I was able to simply add `group by posts.title, posts.content` and it gave me the correct result set.

Comment: Oh, I see now the min/max is just to specify which ID to pull, awesome! Much easier than I thought it out to be.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can also do it without aggregation. Yet I'm not sure if it's a good practice (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225144/why-does-mysql-allow-group-by-queries-without-aggregate-functions) + see comment).

```
SELECT
  posts.id as post_id,
  users.name as author_name,
  posts.title,
  posts.content
FROM
  posts
INNER JOIN
  users
ON
  posts.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY
  users.name, posts.title, posts.content;
```

Comment: The post id will then be arbitrary, which is not a great behaviour of a database. Also, in MySQL 8 that functionality is deprecated and turned off by default. It's generally bad practice, usually unnecessary, and is a rotten code smell.